# Multiple toggle effect using one Jquery call

Tags: jquery

I've a several Jquery toggle effect on my html form and for that i'm using separate id for each html element. How can do that using one jquery function / call?

**What I'm using now :**

```
$("#icon").click(function(){
$(".collasp").toggle("slow");
})  

$("#icon2").click(function(){
$(".collasp2").toggle("slow");
})  

$("#icon3").click(function(){
$(".collasp3").toggle("slow");
})  

$("#icon4").click(function(){
$(".collasp4").toggle("slow");
})  

$("#icon5").click(function(){
$(".collasp5").toggle("slow");
})  

$("#icon6").click(function(){
$(".collasp6").toggle("slow");
})
```

**Html (For example) :**

```
<tr>
  <td colspan="3"><b>Client NI (<?php echo $numclientni; ?>)</b><a    id="icon5">&nbsp;+<hr></td> 
</tr>
<tr>
```

**Update:**

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="275">
<tr>
  <td colspan="3"><b>Cand NI (<?php echo $num_cand; ?>)</b><a id="icon6">&nbsp;+<hr></td> 
</tr>
<tr>
      <td width="120"></td>      
      <td></td>                  
      <td align="right"></td>    
</tr>
<?php
  while($result =  mysqli_fetch_array($get_client_cand)){

    $cdid = (int) $result['cdid'];
    $family_name = inputvalid($result['family_name']);       
    $company = inputvalid($result['company_name']);

    if(strlen($company) >= 15) {
          $company =  substr($company, 0, 14);
    }
    if(strlen($family_name) >= 15) {
          $family_name =  substr($family_name, 0, 14);
    }

    echo "<tr class='collasp6' style='display:none;'>";
    echo "<td>$company</td>";            
    echo "<td>$family_name</td>";            
    echo "<td align='right'><a><label class='' for='modal-15' onclick='show_cand_status($cdid, $p_id)'>Action</label></a></td>";       
    echo "</tr>";
  }

?>  
</table>
```

Comment: Use a common class for all elements to be clicked and an other common class for all `collasp` elements. Then you can use any transversal method to target these specific elements. BUT without seeing all relevant HTML markup, we cannot help you more...

Comment: @A.Wolff you can see that I'm using id `icon5` for this td element. there are 5 other tr element and for that I'm using id `1,2,3..`

Comment: And what is `.collasp5`??? How is it related to `#icon5`? Cannot you use instead transversal method to target specific element? Etc...

Comment: @A.Wolff I updated my question. plz check.

Answer (score 0):

You can compress all of your JS functions into one single function like this:

```
function onItemClick(){
    $(".collasp").toggle("slow");
}

$("#icon").click(onItemClick);
$("#icon2").click(onItemClick);
$("#icon3").click(onItemClick);
$("#icon4").click(onItemClick);
$("#icon5").click(onItemClick);
$("#icon6").click(onItemClick);
```

Or you could set all of your icons to have a `class` such as `icon`:

```
<a id="icon5" class="icon">...</a>
```

and then use:

```
$('.icon').click(onItemClick);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr>
  <td colspan="3"><b>Client NI (<?php echo $numclientni; ?>)</b><a    id="icon5" class="trigger">&nbsp;+<hr></td> 
</tr>
<tr>

$('.trigger').click(function(e) {
    var id = $(e.target).attr('id'); //fetches id of clicked element
    var no = id.replace(/[^0-9]/gi, ''); //gets number in id
    $(".collasp" + no).toggle("slow"); //creates the targeted class and applies toggle effect
});
```